# Bootstrap right hand aside needs to appear above left div in mobile

Tags: bootstrap-4

In desktop view this looks like I would like it, but in mobile view, the aside box moves below the main box.  I would like it on top. How do I do that?

https://jsfiddle.net/b4032v7z/2/

```
<body>
<div class='container'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class='bg-primary text-white col-md-7 offset-md-1'>Main Box
    </div>
    <div class=' bg-danger col-md-3 border-left pr-5'> Aside
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user the order class in bootstrap 4

```
<body>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class="row">
        <div class='bg-primary text-white col-md-7 order-2  order-md-1' >Main Box
        </div>
        <div class=' bg-danger col-md-3 border-left order-1 pr-5  order-md-2' > Aside
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

for more information 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order

Answer (score 1):

Twitter Bootstrap uses display:flex. You can use "order" in your css to control the order of your content.

https://jsfiddle.net/robbiegod/nd95m6xh/

```
.bg-primary {
  height: 100px;
  order: 3;
}

.bg-danger {
  height: 100px;
  order: 1;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .bg-primary {
    order: 1;
  }

  .bg-danger {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

Set that as your default order.

Then in a media query, change the order to the way you want it for desktop.